# How do you find if you have duplicated a hotkey in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, hotkeys

In Notepad++ you can easily assign a HotKey to a majority of menu functions using Settings->Shortcut Mapper. In most programs that allow something similar, you are given a warning if you use a HotKey that is already in use. Say you want to assign "Sort Lines in Ascending Order" to [Ctrl+S], which is currently assigned "Save". In other programs I have used, it will either block you from assigning it or warn you that doing so will disassociate it with the other command. Notepad++ will allow you to duplicate the HotKey and you will be none the wiser. This is fine as long as I know that the HotKey I want to  use is actually not assigned to anything, but there are a ton of commands, especially if you have a couple Plugins installed.

Is there a plugin or a file you can search, or some way to find if a HotKey combination has already been assigned?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: in the Notepad++ directory, *shortcuts.xml* Its format is intuitively obvious to even the most casual observer ;-)

Comment: There are only about 16 lines that look like they could be HotKeys, for example:

`<ScintillaKeys>
        <ScintKey ScintID="2011" menuCmdID="42004" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="90" />`

These could very well be some that I set, they look like they are, but I was looking for all HotKeys, especially the ones that were not set by me. I looked in the other files in that DIR and didn't see anything.